# How to get argument types from Window Object functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, args

I would like to know how I can in typescript acquire all the args types of each function of the object window.

Below as you will see is the type that I have implemented but apparently I am doing it wrong ..

If someone can help me I will appreciate it.

```js
type Arguments<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

const x = (window: Window) => window.alert('hola')
type TestArguments = Arguments<typeof x>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TestArguments` variable is an array of arguments (it even is plural). You need to either:

Access the first element:

```
type Arguments<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

const x = (window: Window) => window.alert('hola')
type TestArgument = Arguments<typeof x>[0];
```

Or `infer` only the first argument.

```
type FirstArgument<F extends Function> = F extends (firstArg: infer A) => any ? A : never;

const x = (window: Window) => window.alert('hola')
type TestArgument = FirstArgument<typeof x>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwK4FsIDtgGcA8AxKCAD2AwBMso8l0BjYASwHt0A+KAXisJPMoAoAdMICGiLAC4oDdADMIcWAEpO7EehBQA-LChT0EAG4KA3AChQkKgzhZg8ZGkz4epdBSo16zNp27E3D35ZGzsHKRl5RRgVDjUNbV19I1MzM1oWOygiP34AdxkyJjypAHVC4tj2AvdiwREAGwVgfgByAAsmBpFWpQtwaDxQ+0RUDHs-BzHMXEsIJlls1gBtAAYAXXM561sRx3GAIT8h3amnYBw5haWTKCA)

Finally, to get only the functions of your function, you would do this:

```
type OnlyFunctions<T> = Pick<T, { [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends Function ? k : never }[keyof T]>
```

This basically maps through the `Window` object, setting `never` to variables that are not functions. Then, get the keys of that array, and use it to construct a new array (using Pick), which only has those keys.

You can combine everything using:

```
type OnlyFunctionsFromFirstArgument = OnlyFunctions<FirstArgument<typeof x>>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=78&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwK4FsIDtgGcA8AxKCAD2AwBMso8l0BjYASwHt0A+KAXisJPMoAoAdMICGiLAC4oDdADMIcWAEpO7EehBQA-LChT0EAG4KA3AChQkKgzhZg8ZGkz4epdBSo16zNp27E3D35ZGzsHKRl5RRgVDjUNbV19I1MzM1oWOygiP34AdxkyJjypAHVC4tj2AvdiwREAGwVgfgByAAsmBpFWpTTLaAB5dAaQajpGTJwAFXYuAAUGWgBrGYAaKABvKABtZel0KGWIECZZKGmAXSlpvcvXPk8Jn0T95ONFAF89k7OLy9YFnAQxGYy8k3QWDwcCYKDwoXsiFQGGAfmGo3G3im8NsiMcKJwAz+RFYrBMQA)

Comment: But how can I extract the type of the args of each function from the window object? For example:

The alert function has these args with this type ..

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that. You can use that type to build up from there.

Comment: Thank you, Do you know how I can test it using console.log () to see the output?